# Command not found on GIT bash

Tags: git, vagrant, vagrantfile

I can run popular simple commands like `ls`, `whoami`. I recently installed vagrant and trying to work around with **GIT**.

When I do:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "D:/GIT/myfolder/try/", 
"/opt/manasa/platform/manasa_server/client", create: true , owner: 
"root", group: "root"
```

I get the following output:

**`bash: config.vm.synced_folder: command not found`**

I am working on Windows 10 and vagrant version :

$ vagrant -v

Vagrant 1.9.8

Can somebody what might be the problem?

Comment: DO you mean you type config.vm.synced_folder in a Git bash session? Or config.vm.synced_folder is part of a vagrant file?

Comment: When i execute this command in Git bash session, i get this error message. @VonC

Comment: @ManasaN. What command are you executing in your git bash session?

Comment: So you do not execute that command, right? You are actually executing the Vagrantfile itself?

Comment: If you want to install git, once SSH'd into your vm, depending on your vm os lets call it unix, we can run sudo apt-get install git-all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line should be a part of your `Vagrantfile`. You should not run that line in your terminal.

See [here](https://github.com/therobinkim/lets-learn-vagrant/blob/master/Vagrantfile#L26) for an example of how I've used that line in my `Vagrantfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Those lines must be placed between

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
```

and

```
end
```

in your Vagrantfile

Comment: I have these lines in my vagrantfile. @sensorario

Comment: Could you paste here your VagrantFile?

Answer (score 0):

You must start vagrant with the command `vagrant up` in the same directory as your vagrant config file.
You cannot execute a vagrant config file in bash.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the vagrantfile is < 2.
Edit with this one and it will work

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

rtuniki
rtuniki@gmail.com